# Starting certain Workflows by certain Usergroups

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, permissions, sharepoint-permissions

is it possible that only certain usergroups are allowed to start certain workflows?
As an example I got 3 groups A, B and C and the workflows 1, 2 and 3.

A shall not be able to start any workflow while B can start workflows 1 and C is allowed to start 2 and 3.

Edit:
It's Sharepoint 2016 on Premise and the workflows should be started manually

Comment: Which version of SharePoint is it? Workflow 2010 or 2013? Is this workflow started manually or run automatically?

Comment: It's Sharepoint 2016 on Premise and the workflows should be started manually

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, usually users with editing permissions can start a workflow manually.

If you want to set permissions for users, you could try to set some settings in the workflow according to your needs.

For example:
[image]
[image]